# MySQL Query to select from table specific rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which looks has the following values:

| product_id | custom_id | custom_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | A |
| 1 | 9 | V |
| 2 | 10 | B |
| 3 | 3 | Q |

I am looking for a mysql query to get all values from product_id once and select the row which has custom_id = "10" in case it is available. Nevertheless in case custom_id = 10 is not available for a product_id I would still like to return the product_id but also only once.

So the result I am looking for is

| product_id | custom_id | custom_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | A |
| 2 | 10 | B |
| 3 | NULL | NULL |

Could please someone direct me in the right direction.

```
select product_id, custom_id, custom_value from table where custom_id = 10
```

does of course only return the values for product_id "1" and "2"

Answer (score 1):

You can select the first set of rows, then union by a distinct of all the other product id's

```
select product_id, custom_id, custom_value from table where custom_id = 10 
union
select distinct product_id, NULL as custom_id, NULL as custom_value where custom_id <> 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first generate a `ROW_NUMBER` to get the first element for each "*product_id*", then transform to NULL values for which "*product_id*" does not match your value 10, using the `IF` function.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY custom_id = 10 DESC) AS rn
    FROM tab
)
SELECT product_id, 
       IF(custom_id=10,    custom_id, NULL) AS custom_id, 
       IF(custom_id=10, custom_value, NULL) AS custom_value 
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ewJaDdjdEyfPR7owaTkUGm/0).